# Разбор sqlite файла (C#)

Tags: c#, sqlite

Такая ситуация:

Есть одна онлайн игра, содержащая временные данные о персонаже/персонажах в локальной sqlite бд. Дабы не лезть в память, интересует метод чтения данных прямо из базы. Нашёл два способа взаимодействия с ней:

1. System.Data.SQLite
2. Sqlite-net

Всё реализовал, работает на УРА, но вот только незначительная проблема, которую мне хотелось бы решить: все эти файлы требуют библиотеки, и в результате всё приложение и прилегающие к нему файлы весят не менее 2мб! Хотя функционал из библиотек используется минимальный: я всего-лишь читаю данные и вывожу их на на экран, менять/удалять мне не надо. Так вот, возможно ли спарсить данные напрямую из файла? Ну аля

```
using(FileStream FStream = File.OpenFile())...
```

Или же обязательно использовать эти библы?

Заранее благодарен за годный ответ!

Comment: Проще использовать готовые библиотеки. Один раз скачать пару мб не проблема, особенно в онлайн играх.

Answer (score 1):

В библиотеках, о которых идёт речь, находится сама СУБД SQLite. Читайте её ядро. Без них работать с БД формата SQLite не возможно. Конечно, если Вы не планируете делать самостоятельную реализацию. Однако это совершенно не оправдано с точки зрения затрат труда и времени.

> в результате всё приложение и прилегающие к нему файлы весят не менее
>   2мб!

При современном уровне технологий хранения информации и качестве связи 2 Мб это настолько несущественный размер, что не нет смысла заморачиваться по данному поводу.

Используйте готовые библиотеки для работы SQLite.

Comment: Недавно нашёл реализацию моего желания. Но проблема в том, что она на ассемблере. Сумел перевести только 1/5 когда - чтение заголовка файла и информацию о размерах таблицы, дальше не осилил. Ну да ладно, будем рыть, спасибо!